# How to locate the instruction by an address under WinXp?

Tags: windows, gcc, gdb, malloc, mingw32

I have had my program running on MINGW32 in WinXp. The program is complied by gcc and get the expected result with gdb debug tool. But when directly run it under MINGW32, the WinXp will report errors that:

"0x7c956a6e" instruction have referenced the memory of "0x00000000". This memory cannot be "read".

Then how to locate this instruction? I have checked and it seems caused by a malloc function. The source code is as below：

```
int find(FILE *fp, char **head) {
    char str[100];
    char *p, c;
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    do {
        c = fgetc(fp);
        if(c == EOF)
            return 0;
    } while(c == ' ' || c == '\n');

    while(c != ' ' && c != '\n') {
        str[i++] = c;
        c = fgetc(fp);
    } 

    *head = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * i);
    if(*head == NULL)
        printf("\nCannot get memory (find)");
    else {
        p = *head;
        for(j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            *(p++) = str[j];
        }
        *p = '\0';
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It is appreciated if anyone can help!

10/7 Thanks for the comments. Here is the rest of the code and the data pattern:

```
int main() 
{
    FILE *fp;
    int lines = 0,  i = 0;
    TianYa *yp, *linep;
    char *head = NULL;

    fp = fopen("tysample.txt", "r");

    if(fp == NULL)
        printf("\nCannot open file");
    else {
        yp = (TianYa *)malloc(TIAN_YA_LINES * sizeof(TianYa));
        if(yp == NULL)
            printf("\nCannot get memory (main)");
        else {
            linep = yp;
            i = 0;
            while(find(fp, &head) != 0) {
                switch(i++) {
                    case 0:
                        linep->name = head;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        linep->passwd = head;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        linep->email = head;
                        i = 0;
                        linep++;
                        lines++;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    linep = yp;
    for(i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        printf("\nName:%s, Passwd:%s, Email:%s", linep->name, linep->passwd, linep->email);
/*      free(linep->name);
        free(linep->passwd);
        free(linep->email);
*/      linep++;
    }

    free(yp);
    yp = NULL;
    linep = NULL;

    if(fclose(fp))
        printf("\nFailed to close file");

    return 0;
}


momre           123456           baitianyang@live.cn
白天也懂           123456           baitianyedong@tianya.cn
baitiansosuo           weirenminfuwu           baitianyouxiang@sohu.com
heng__chang           87732351           baitianyu.06@163.com
风正                           5581100           baitianyu@126.com
sparkbai           20001228           baitianyu@tianya.cn
背粪篓进银行           19851019           baitianyu123@163.com
白天月           11200929           baitianyue@126.com
```

Comment: The error isn't caused by a call to malloc (though it is memory related), but rather by your program writing to memory that it shouldn't. Without seeing the rest of the program, it's not possible to say with any degree of certainty where the problem is. However, the code-snippet that you have posted *may* produce that kind of an error on lines 13, 21, 23 and 25 (every spot that writes to memory) More code could well get a better answer. :)

Comment: @enhzflep `This memory cannot be "read"`. This error is not "write" related ;)

Comment: Thought, you calling `find` with head==NULL. Dereferencing of NULL produces your exception.

Comment: That'll learn me for skimming the error message. I must admit I did miss the word 'read'. Reading your comment and looking at the address makes it seem perfectly obvious. My ++

Comment: I just updated the rest of the code, hope you can help to investigate, thanks!!

Comment: As far as I can see, you assign `'\0'` to `(*head)[i]`, but the last element in `*head` is `(*head)[i-1]` (assuming `i != 0`).